# Automatic theorem proving

Tags: prolog, theorem-proving

I'm looking for an automatic theorem proving system, which can prove this:

Crocodile took mans child. Man asked crocodile not to eat his child. But Crocodile said: I'll return your child to you, if you will tell me, what am I going to do with him.

Analytical solution to his looks like this:

x - crocodile will eat child
y - men answers: crocodile will eat child

~ means equality, ! means not, -> implies, + OR;

```
((x~y)->!x) and  ((x XOR y)->x) =
(x! and y +!x and y+!x)(!x!y+x and y+x) =
(!x+!y)(x+!y) = !y;
```

So, the answers is that men has to say: "You are not going to eat the child";

Now, there are plenty of systems listed here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving

I've tried 5-6 of them, but couldn't really understand what am I doing here. How to formalize this theorem inside them, so that I could enter this first part of it:

`((x~y)->!x) and  ((x XOR y)->x)`

and get the answer

`y` as an output.

Can any once advice, which system at least capable of doing so automatically, and give me some more hints?

Regards,
Konstantin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of reserach, I actually found out there are many programs like this, so my answer is : yes, such theorem can be proved automatically. Online example: http://logik.phl.univie.ac.at/~chris/gateway/formular-uk-zentral.html

Comment: Could you share the code for the crocodile problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question target it's a lot higher than usual, I don't understand sufficiently your task to help...

I just goggled 'tableaux in Prolog', and would suggest to try first the [simpler one](https://github.com/tchap/prolog-tableaux), before delving into [something more sophisticated](http://www.leancop.de/lintap/) (but I don't even know if that kind of logic is appropriate for your task).

Comment: Thank you, that is actually a good start. I've also founded SATCHMO sources written in PROLOG, will try it our too. My problem is that I do not know - if that formula is really can be solved automatically as general cause, but I think so, and so I hope someone can approve that and point me into right direction. But anyway, I'll be not wasting my time, and meanwhile will try to implement it using PROLOG myself.  The actual solving algorithm is not very hard: base on some rules, formula is simplified on every step (like, we can replace x-> with x` and y, until we have conjunctions and negation

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux - actually maybe this is exactly what I need, from wikipedia I can see that it is very close to. I'll try this method now

Answer (score 0):

Checkout prolog. It's great for logical propositions and that sort of thing. Start with a read through the wiki and see if it sounds like what you want. It is a logical programming language - it will help you to build your own theorem proving algorithms.

Wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog

Tutorials:
http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/courses/esslli04prolog/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to solve this using prolog and failed. I can, actually, write solver for this particular task, but I want something which solves many analogical ones, and I can not do it myself. In Prolog, for instances, I will need to write dual clause form to represent any formula as conjunctions and negations only and e.t.c, many other things to take into account, not very trivial task. That is I want to select something from the ready open-source solutions and start studying them. But I can' find any which can solve that formula I've provided